# CSS background image position based on mouse position

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with a background image which changes it's position based on the mouse position. What it basically does is create an animation of somebody turning their head (check out http://www.fore6.com/?p=533 to give you a better idea.

I can get it working fine, however, I have 3 different images that appear next to each other. How can I get each image to animate independently? At the moment they all animate in unison together, but they should animate differently because the mouse will always be in a different position relative to each image. I'm thinking that maybe i should use a loop, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

My jQuery code is:

```
var aniX = null;
var aniY = null;

aniX = $('.anim-photo').offset().left;
aniY = $('.anim-photo').offset().top;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var mousePos = new Array(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    interact(mousePos, ["0px", "-288px", "-576px"]);
})

function interact(mouseCord, aniCord) {
    if (mouseCord[0] < aniX && mouseCord[1] < aniY){ // Box-1
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[0]+" 0px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > aniX && mouseCord[0] < aniX+285 && mouseCord[1] < aniY){ // Box-2
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[1]+" 0px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > aniX+285 && mouseCord[1] < aniY){ // Box-3
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[2]+" 0px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] < aniX && mouseCord[1] > aniY && mouseCord[1] < aniY+357){ // Box-4
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[0]+" -360px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > aniX && mouseCord[0] < aniX+285 && mouseCord[1] > aniY && mouseCord[1] < aniY+357){ // Box-5
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[1]+" -360px");

}else if (mouseCord[0] > aniX+285 && mouseCord[1] > aniY && mouseCord[1] < aniY+357){ // Box-6
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[2]+" -360px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] < aniX && mouseCord[1] > aniY+357){ // Box-7
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[0]+" -720px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > aniX && mouseCord[0] < aniX+285 && mouseCord[1] > aniY+357){ // Box-8
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[1]+" -720px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > aniX+285 && mouseCord[1] > aniY+357){ // Box-9
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[2]+" -720px");
}
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create three different calls to `interact(mousePos, ["0px", "-288px", "-576px"]);` one for each image with mousePos and the second parameter being the *object/coordinates of the object* that you're currently animating. Also create separate classes for each or *provide the jQuery object* you're currently animating as a parameter to your interact function

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually already did it that way which works fine. I was just trying to figure out if it can be done in one function, rather than three :-)